# How to update a table column with enabled checkbox values when I click on submit button

Tags: checkbox, tableview, javafx-8, fxml

I have the fxml file with two tabs (tab 1 and tab 2), tab 1 having table view with only one column, tab 2 having multiple checkbox and submit button, when I enable the checkbox and click on submit button, I am able to get the value/text of an enabled checkbox but how to update the enabled checkbox values into a tableview (which is in tab 1) when I click the submit button ?

Please help me, Thanks in advance

Below the fxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="373.0" prefWidth="535.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.45">
   <children>
      <TabPane layoutX="4.0" layoutY="5.0" prefHeight="363.0" prefWidth="529.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
        <tabs>
          <Tab text="Table tab">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <TableView fx:id="table" layoutX="56.0" layoutY="7.0" prefHeight="299.0" prefWidth="395.0">
                          <columns>
                            <TableColumn fx:id="column" prefWidth="339.0" text="Enabled checkbox values" />
                          </columns>
                        </TableView>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab text="Checkbox tab">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <CheckBox fx:id="box1" layoutX="92.0" layoutY="46.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="CheckBox 1" />
                        <CheckBox fx:id="box2" layoutX="92.0" layoutY="101.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="CheckBox 2" />
                        <CheckBox fx:id="box3" layoutX="92.0" layoutY="156.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="CheckBox  3" />
                        <Button fx:id="submit" layoutX="350.0" layoutY="249.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Submit" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I was just added the below code in my controller.java, Now table is updating with enabled checkbox value once I clicked submit button but when I select on third checkbox, Table is updated with third row not in a first row.

```
final ObservableList<Table> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Table(column1R1, val1, column3R1),
                new Table(column1R2, val2, column3R2),
                new Table(column1R3, val3, column3R3)
                );
```

I know I have statically declared the table row, but I dont know how to dynamically update the table with enabled checkbox values once I click on submit button.

Any Idea ? Please help me.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Is your question simply of how to submit the data from *tab 2* into *tab 1*'s `TableView`? And why just one column - doesn't seem to make much sense - use a `ListView` then. Since you can append any kind of `Class` with the `TableView` you could provide a custom model object (e.g. `MyModel`) and add it to the `ObservableList<MyModel>`that you schould have set to be the `TableView`'s items.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes submit the data from tab 2 should be the result of updating table with enabled checkbox value. Actual table design have three column but reaming two column are static so no worries about two column, Can you please give me example code, I am new to javafx

Comment: Hi Please give me a sample code

Comment: We are a bit lazy, aren't we? You can find everything you need for this relativly simple task on the [Client Technologies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm) tutorials of Oracle. Especially the one for [FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/why_use_fxml.htm) (because you will need to do this in the `FXML`s controller) and the other one for [TableView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm). There you can find an example almost fitting for your needs (the fact, that you are using a `TabPane` doesn't matter)

Comment: @dzim

Added the observation which I was tried, Kindly assist me

Thanks in advance.